# how to pass variable value with double quote in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

```
USER_UID=$1
echo 'generate_token("$USER_UID")'
```

I want output like

```
generate_token("1234567")
```

i tried multiple ways but didn't worked. it just print same line without value generate_jwt("$USER_UID")

Comment: Use `printf 'generate_token("%s")\n' "$1"`

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use single quotes, it causes the shell to preserve the literal value of each character within the quotes. This means the `$` will be treated as a literal `$` character.

You should use double quotes:

```sh
USER_UID="$1"
echo "generate_token(\"$USER_UID\")"
```

From the [bash man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), under the **Quoting** section:

> Enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of **$**, **`**, **\**, and, when history expansion is enabled, **!**.

For POSIX details on quoting, see [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02).

Example in an interactive shell:

```sh
$ USER_UID='foo'
$ echo "generate_token(\"$USER_UID\")"
generate_token("foo")
```

This will also work if `USER_UID` contains spaces:

```sh
$ USER_UID='var with spaces'
$ echo "generate_token(\"$USER_UID\")"
generate_token("var with spaces")
```

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks for pointing that out, I updated my answer to correctly add the double quotes in the output.

Comment: Works for me, though as a matter of style and to avoid the possibility of `$USER_UID` being subject to word splitting, I would personally use `'generate_token("'"$USER_UID"'")'` or, better, `"generate_token(\"$USER_UID\")"`.

Comment: echo "generate_token(\"$USER_UID\")"
this worked fine.